# Radical of finitely generated ideal in commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $I\subset R$ be a finitely generated ideal, here $R$ is a commutative ring with identity. Then $(\sqrt{I})^r\subset I$ for some $r\in\mathbb{N}$.

This is what I encountered when reading a note on algebraic geometry. It seems quite trivial for the author, because very soon he turned to another subject. But not for me...could someone explain it in details?

Comment: I is finite generated.By the definition of radical ideal,isn't this conclusion easily?

Comment: Maybe $\sqrt I$ is supposed to be finitely generated?

Comment: @k.stm At least it is so when $R$ is noetherian?

Comment: @user498029 Yes. Then pic generators $x_1, …, x_n$ of $\sqrt I$ and find a common exponent $s$ such that all of $x_1^s$, …, $x_n^s$ are in $I$ *and then* take $r = n(s-1) + 1$. (You need to do this because in the worst case scenario $x_1^{s-1}·…·x_n^{s-1}$ may not be in $I$.)

Comment: Another sufficient condition is for $R/I$ to be Noetherian. For then the nil ideal $\sqrt{I}/I$ must be nilpotent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t see how this is even true in general. The null ideal is always finitely generated, but the nil radical of a ring may not be nilpotent. For example in $ℚ[X_1, X_2, X_3, …]/(X_1^1, X_2^2, X_3^3…)$.